# combo box with countries as its id, and an input text that will do the autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I made a combo box that contain country with it's id, and I also have a input text that will do the autocomplete. If I select one of the country from the combo box, I want input text will show me, when I press some words with autocomplete function, all of the city that include in that country (assuming I have it in my database).

sample code below

form

---

```
          City:
           <select name="city" id="city" />
             <option value="">-- First Select State --</option> 
             <option value="">Bangalore</option>
             <option value="">Mumbai</option>
             <option value="">Chennai</option>
             <option value="">Gujrath</option>
          </select>

          Area :  
          <input id="loction" name="loction" type="text" />




script
   --------

         $(document).ready(function() {

           $("#loction").autocomplete("get_course.php",
                          {
                           extraParams: {
                           country: function() { return $("#city").val(); }
                           }
                });
            });
```

mysql[get_course.php]

---

```
       require_once "connection.php";
   $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
   if (!$q) return;

    $cty = $_GET["city"];


       $sql = "select DISTINCT area as area 
                    from table_name
                    where area LIKE '%$q%' and    city = '".$cty."' ";

          $rsd = mysql_query($sql);

         while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) 
             {
    $cname = $rs['area'];
    echo "$cname\n";

            }
```

Comment: Show what you tried out yet. (jsfiddle)?

Answer (score 0):

In your `get_course.php` you try to get a search pattern out of the array element `$_GET["city"]` but in your `extraParams` data structure, that you send using `autocomplete`, you define an object with the name `country`. Could that be the mistake?

Try evaluating the array element `$_GET["country"]`:

```
$cty = $_GET["country"];
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT area FROM table_name "
      ."WHERE area LIKE '%$q%' AND city ='$cty'";
```